# deploy servlet-war into oc4j container

Tags: java, oracle, oc4j

may i knwo is it possible to run  app.war (servlet web app) on oc4-oracle10 ? i tried deployed the most simple example but doesn work. is oc4j can only run ejb web app?  if there anyway to run servlet webapp on oc4j? any guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OC4J requires EAR files, so you'll have to [wrap your web archive into an enterprise archive](http://www.querycat.com/question/981fce147a3e8950324ffb17cc25b9d6).

Comment: For further information on this topic: send "oc4j war" to your famous search engine.

Answer (score 0):

OC4J can certainly deploy WAR files just fine. It does the "wrapping" itself.

It would be better if you could provide the errors OC4J is giving when you deploy your application.